# How to store note only on my Mac in Notes 4?

Tags: macos, notes.app

I'm trying the new Notes.app version 4 with El Capitan. I "upgraded" my existing data to be compatible wit the newly revamped version of this app.

I have an "iCloud" group on the left panel, with a couple folders. But I do not have an "On my Mac" group.

So how do I store notes only on my Mac rather than through iCloud?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Choose `Notes` > `"On My Mac" Account`

I have just opened Notes on El Capitan to verify this. Please click on **Notes** in the menu bar, then click on `"On My Mac" Account` to access the local storage facility. The new group will appear upon clicking this option.

[image: Notes]

[image: Group]

Comment: Yes, this is a solution.

Comment: @BasilBourque Good to hear it's worked!